# Error message after installing client "There was an error while accessing the configuration file at /home/NextCloud: ...:

Tags: nextcloud

I'm using Ubuntu desktop 18.04 and wouldlike to install nextcloud client to set up a gui for various cloud storage providers. I was following along with this blog post: https://websiteforstudents.com/install-nextcloud-desktop-client-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-desktop/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nextcloud-devs/client 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install nextcloud-client
```

After this I do see nextcloud as an app in my Applications menu. But when I click it I get a popup box with the error message:

> There was an error while accessing the configuration file at
> /home/doug/.config/Nextcloud/nextcloud.cfg. Please make sure the file
> can be accessed by your user.

What should I do here?

[Edit]
A comenter asked me to post the output of ls:

```
ls -al /home/doug/.config/Nextcloud/nextcloud.cfg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 718 Nov 27 18:39 /home/doug/.config/Nextcloud/nextcloud.cfg
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /home/doug/.config/Nextcloud/nextcloud.cfg`.

Comment: Hi @heynnema OK, added a comment now. Any pointers most welcome

Comment: Try `sudo chmod 777 /home/doug/.config/Nextcloud/nextcloud.cfg` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it - thanks! Should I leave it at 777?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way it'll work.

Comment: We also could have changed the owner from root:root to doug:doug, but that might have broken it to nextcloud.

Comment: Got it. Well thank you. Let me know if I should delete my post, or if you would like to make your comment an answer?

Comment: I'll make a quick answer for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls -al /home/doug/.config/Nextcloud/nextcloud.cfg` shows us:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 718 Nov 27 18:39 /home/doug/.config/Nextcloud/nextcloud.cfg
```

This says the file is owned by root and only writable by root.

We did:

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/doug/.config/Nextcloud/nextcloud.cfg
```

And that allows it to work (without changing file ownership).